# Finding Last Day of Previous Month in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I'm a little unsure why this is not able to find the last day of the previous month.  Every steps seems to be working correctly, except when the final date is created.

```
<?php

$currentMonth = date('n');
$currentYear = date('Y');

if($currentMonth == 1) {
    $lastMonth = 12;
    $lastYear = $currentYear - 1;
}
else {
    $lastMonth = $currentMonth -1;
    $lastYear = $currentYear;
}

if($lastMonth < 10) {
    $lastMonth = '0' . $lastMonth;
}

$lastDayOfMonth = date('t', $lastMonth);

$lastDateOfPreviousMonth = $lastYear . '-' . $lastMonth . '-' . $lastDayOfMonth;

$newLastDateOfMonth = date('F j, Y', strtotime($lastDateOfPreviousMonth));

?>
```

`$lastDateOfPreviousMonth` is returning 2012-09-30 as expected; however, after trying to convert it to September 30, 2012 - `$newLastDateOfMonth` is returning October 1, 2012.  Where do I seem to be going wrong?

EDIT:  If using `date("t/m/Y", strtotime("last month"));` or `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of previous month'));` will either of these still be viable given 2013-01-01, i.e. will they account for the change in year?

Comment: My calendar only has 30 days in September (and April, June and November) - all the rest have 31 - except for February (where year % 4 ? 28 : 29 is a good approximation, but doesn't scan, let alone rhyme)

Comment: Haha yea I just caught that also, just a typo - fixed it.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of previous month'));
//2012-09-30
```

or

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify("last day of previous month");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Later edit: [php.net documentation - relative formats for strtotime(), DateTime and date_create()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: Good deal, looks like codepad.org needs to update their shattt. Check it http://codepad.org/umWDS84h

Comment: Will your first answer still work if the date is 2013-01-01 to account for the change in year?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter what month/year.

Comment: If you check the last code, the one with `DateTime` and change it to `$date = new DateTime('2013-01-01');` it will output: `2012-12-31`

Comment: Where can i find the documentation for this? Can you provide me the link.

Comment: @Kshitiz [php.net - relative formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: Why not `$date = new \DateTime("last day of previous month");` ?

Answer (score 23):

There is a php function for this.

```
echo date("t/m/Y", strtotime("last month"));
```

Comment: Ya, didn't know about that, very nice. +1

Comment: @pennstate_fanboy yes, but you have to do: `echo date('F j, Y', strtotime(date("Y-m-t", strtotime("last month"))));` to make it work.

Comment: I don't think I was fully clear, I meant will it still work if the date is 2013-01-01, and convert it to 2012-12-31?...Also, I tried just `date('F t, Y', strtotime(last month));` and still received September 30, 2012

Comment: `date("Y-m-t", strtotime("last month", strtotime($currentDate)));` will give last day of previous month where `$currentDate` can be any date.

Comment: `strtotime("last month");` doesn't really work [on 31st of every month](https://gist.github.com/garak/1000118)

Answer (score 4):

First day of this month, minus 1 second.

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 second',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y'))));
```

Example [here](http://codepad.org/ZnWB48pl).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strtotime()`'s zero handling functionality to achieve this also:

```
# Day Before
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-03-00')); // 2016-02-29

# Year can be handled too
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-01-00')); // 2015-12-31

# Month Before
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-00-01')); // 2015-12-01

# Month AND Day
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-00-00')); // 2015-11-30
```

*Makes sense if you think of 00 as 'one less than the first (01)'.*

So to achieve the objective of this question, 'last day of previous month' is a simple case of

```
date('your_format', strtotime('YYYY-ThisMonth-00'));
# So:
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-11-00')); // 2016-10-31
```

Answer (score 2):

please try with below answer.

code:

```
echo date("t/m/Y", strtotime(date('Y-m')." -1 month"));
```

You will get last day of previous 12 months.

Example:

```
    <?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $months[] = date("t/m/Y l", strtotime(date('Y-m')." -$i months"));
}
print_r($months);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 30/11/2018 Monday
    [1] => 31/10/2018 Friday
    [2] => 30/09/2018 Wednesday
    [3] => 31/08/2018 Sunday
    [4] => 31/07/2018 Thursday
    [5] => 30/06/2018 Tuesday
    [6] => 31/05/2018 Saturday
    [7] => 30/04/2018 Thursday
    [8] => 31/03/2018 Monday
    [9] => 28/02/2018 Monday
    [10] => 31/01/2018 Friday
    [11] => 31/12/2017 Tuesday
)
```

Comment: `strtotime("-1 months")` This does not work if there are 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

##### Precision-based approach (PHP 7.1+):

If you don't want the ambiguity of string-based manipulations, here's an alternative using `DateTime` with **microsecond-precision**:

```php
$today = new DateTime('now');

$last_day_of_prev_month = (clone $today)
  ->setDate( $today->format('Y'), $today->format('m'), 1 )
  ->setTime( 0, 0, 0, -1 );
```

---

###### Expanded solution w/ explanation:

```php
$today = new DateTime('now'); // 2023-12-28 22:19:57.175254

// Set the DAY to the 1st ()
$first_day_of_month = $today->setDate( $today->format('Y'), $today->format('m'), 1 );
// Set the TIME to 00:00:00.999999 (you'll see why in next step)
$first_day_of_month->setTime( 0, 0, 0, 999999 ); // or (0,0,0,-1)

// subtract exactly 1 second from date (using DateInterval syntax)
$last_day_of_prev_month = $first_day_of_month->sub( new DateInterval('PT1S') );

echo $last_day_of_prev_month->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u'); // 2023-11-30 23:59:59.999999
```

###### Explanation

1. Get current date and time `2023-12-28 22:19:57.175254`
2. [Set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php) the year and month to the same, but change DAY to the 1st `// 2023-12-01 22:19:57.175254`
3. [Set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) the hour, minutes and seconds to 00, and microseconds to 999999 `// 2023-12-01 00:00:00.999999`
4. [Subtract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) by 1 SECOND `// 2023-11-30 23:59:59.999999`

**Steps #3 and #4 can be substituted for: `$first_day_of_month->setTime( 0, 0, 0, -1 );`**, which automatically zeroes the time and subtracts by 1 microsecond. But, I wanted this to be understandable, so I left this out of the expanded solution.

###### Why, though?

- Using `DateTime` objects makes datetime handling much easier, like for instance, you can ***compare*** two different DateTime objects (e.g. check if a datetime is within a month).
- Not everyone is a fan of text-based parsing approaches that leave room for unreliability, unambiguity and for more errors to occur.

###### Note

- This is based on *your* timezone (or your server's) by default, so make sure to define a timezone when comparing datetimes between different systems (e.g. client and server), ok? :)

  - E.g.: `$today = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone("UTC"));`